# curl script is including the "-d" param in my URL, but I don't want it to

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm using bash shell on Mac Yosemite.  I have the followign script ...

```
    #!/bin/bash

    curl -u "mysecret:password!" "https://mydomein.org/myproject/oauth/token" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

When I run the script, I get the error

```
    davea$ sh curl.sh
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /myproject/oauth/token -d was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at mydomain.org Port 80</address>
    </body></html>
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grant_type=client_credentials
```

I don't want the "-d" to be part fo my URl, which is why I put the quotes around the URL, but I don't know how to rewrite the script to get the URL by itself, and then send the stuff after "-d" as param
etrs.

Comment: From `man curl`: `curl [options] [URL...]`

Comment: From this I'm to understand that you're suggesting moving the parameters in front of the URL, but that results in teh URL I listed in teh comment to the other person's answer.

Comment: Check your script with `cat -A script` or `cat -v script` for special nonprinting characters.

Answer (score 3):

While you would normally put options before the URL, curl doesn't actually insist on that usage.

However, options (and, in general, command line arguments) must be separated from each other by spaces, not typographical variants of spaces (em spaces, non-breaking spaces, etc.) Many word processors are wont to insert typographical symbols (including typographical quotes and long dashes) in order to make your documents look prettier. That's cool for human readers but it generally confuses software, so you should avoid using these features when you are editing shell scripts and other programs.

Try editing that script with a programmers editor; I don't know what you might have on your Mac, but there is surely something that will not modify what you type. Or turn off (typically in "preferences") whatever typographical substitutions are being performed and retype the line with just spaces and dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
curl -u 'mysecret:password!' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://mydomein.org/myproject/oauth/token'
```

curl --help on my system tells me direct at the top of the long help page:

```
$ curl --help
Usage: curl [options...] <url>
```

So I guess when you put the HTTP POST data in the place of the options before the URL all should work well.

Comment: Running your script resulted in the error "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grant_type=client_credentials"